# mmap() return not passed between functions

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, mmap

I am sure I am missing something simple but I have been knocking my head against the proverbial wall for a few days and still no closer after reading mmap several times and googling.

I have a (condensed) program here where a shared memory space is used to try and enable debugs/tracing whilst the program is running but I am at the first stage of trying to return a mmap pointer back to the main routine without worrying about the caller yet.

The main routine calls the POSIX shared memory functions in another routine (sharedmemoryv.c) and that seems to have successful returns for shm_open, ftruncate and mmap, however when control is reverted back to the main routine, the return for mmap is NULL (*debug_flag) resulting in a SEGV error.

Any nudge or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Output of running the application is as follows:

```
./STACKOVERFLOW.o 
PError is: : Success
IN SHARED MEMORY FNT1 0
IN SHARED MEMORY FNT2 1
debug flag is null
Segmentation fault
```

GDB shows that it is indeed related to the debug_flag not having anything assigned to it when previously it did.

```
debug flag is null

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400a4c in print_debug (debug_flag=0x0, title_string=0x400cad "debug prog", first_string=0x400c9e "finishing main", second_string=0x400c9d "") at debug.c:8
8       if(DEBUG_ON == *debug_flag)
```

main.c:

```
     1  
     2  #include <stdio.h>
     3  #include <stdlib.h>
     4  
     5  #include "debug.h"
     6  #include "sharedmemoryv.h"
     7  #include "sharedmemory.h"
     8  
     9  
    10  int *debug_flag = NULL;
    11  
    12  int main(void)
    13  {
    14      enum data_type { TYPE_INT_SIGNED, TYPE_LONG_LONG_SIGNED, TYPE_CHAR_SIGNED };
    15  
    16      enum data_type type_for_debug = TYPE_INT_SIGNED;
    17  
    18      shared_memory_variable(type_for_debug, debug_flag, DEBUG_FLAG_1);   
    19  
    20      if(debug_flag == NULL)
    21      {
    22           printf("%s\n", "debug flag is null");
    23      }
    24      print_debug(debug_flag, "debug prog", "finishing main", BLANK_STRING);
    25  
    26      return 0;
    27  }
```

sharedmemoryv.c:

```
     1  #include <stdio.h>
     2  #include <sys/mman.h>
     3  #include <sys/stat.h>        
     4  #include <fcntl.h>           
     5  #include <unistd.h>
     6  #include <sys/types.h>
     7  #include <string.h>
     8  #include <stdlib.h>
     9  #include <errno.h>
    10  
    11  #include "debug.h"
    12  
    13  int shared_memory_variable(int type, void *variable, char *shared_memory_reference)
    14  {
    15      enum data_type { TYPE_INT_SIGNED, TYPE_LONG_LONG_SIGNED, TYPE_CHAR_SIGNED };
    16      int shared_memory_fd = 0;
    17  
    18          shm_unlink(shared_memory_reference);
    19  
    20      if(-1 == (shared_memory_fd = shm_open(shared_memory_reference, O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_EXCL, S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO)))
    21          {
    22                  fprintf(stdout, "%s%s\n", "Could not create a shared memory segment for ", shared_memory_reference);
    23                  return -1;
    24          }
    25  
    26      if(0 != ftruncate(shared_memory_fd, sizeof(int)))
    27      {
    28          printf("%s\n", "ftruncate has an error");
    29          perror("ftruncate error is ");
    30      }
    31      if(MAP_FAILED == (variable = mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shared_memory_fd, 0)))
    32      {
    33          printf("%s\n", "POINTER ALLOCATION FAILED FOR MMAP");
    34      }
    35      perror("PError is: ");
    36      printf("%s%d\n", "IN SHARED MEMORY FNT1 ", *(int *) variable);
    37      *(int *) variable = DEBUG_ON;
    38      printf("%s%d\n", "IN SHARED MEMORY FNT2 ", *(int *) variable);
    39  
    40      close(shared_memory_fd);
    41      return 0;
    42  }
```

debug.c

```
     1  #include <stdio.h>
     2  
     3  #define DEBUG_ON 1
     4  #define DEBUG_OFF 0
     5  
     6  int print_debug(int *debug_flag, const char *title_string, const char *first_string, const char *second_string)
     7  {
     8      if(DEBUG_ON == *debug_flag)
     9      {
    10          fprintf(stdout, "%s%s%s%s%s\n", title_string, ": ", first_string," ",  second_string);
    11  
    12      }
    13      return 0;
    14  }
```

For completeness, the header files are shown below:

debug.h

```
     1  extern int *debug_flag;
     2  
     3  int print_debug(int *debug_flag, const char *title_string, const char *first_string, const char *second_string);
     4  
     5  #define BLANK_STRING ""
     6  #define DEBUG_ON 1
     7  #define DEBUG_OFF 0
     8
```

sharedmemory.h

```
    1   #define DEBUG_FLAG_1 "/debug_flag_1"
```

sharedmemoryv.h

```
    1   int shared_memory_variable(int type, void *variable, char *shared_memory_reference);
```

Comment: the '    enum data_type { TYPE_INT_SIGNED, TYPE_LONG_LONG_SIGNED, TYPE_CHAR_SIGNED };' should be in (for instance) the sharedmemoryv.h file, then there is only one place that it is defined, only one place that maintenance needs to be performed, and there is assurance that all files are using the exact same enum definition.

Comment: sharedmemoryv.c should have: #include "sharedmemoryv.h"  and debug.c should have: #include "debug.h"  Without those statements, the compiler will raise warnings about the functions in the file(s) and them assume that the returned value and all the parameters are int.  That can/will be a problem.

Comment: you assigned null to the debug flag in main.c with this statement: '10  int *debug_flag = NULL;'

Comment: Good note on the ENUM data types. It is known that NULL assigned is to *debug_flag. When declaring a pointer, I assign to NULL initially if I am not using it immediately via a malloc or some other call so any calls to it not initialised show immediate errors. I am expecting this NULL to be replaced by mmap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now you're passing a NULL in `debug_flag` to `shared_memory_variable` via the `void *variable` parameter.  Since you've passed it by value, the function cannot modify it!

You need to pass a *pointer* to `debug_flag` to `shared_memory_variable`:

```
int shared_memory_variable(int type, void **variable, char *shared_memory_reference)
{
    // ...
     if(MAP_FAILED == (*variable = mmap
```

and

```
int *debug_flag = NULL;

int main(void)
{
    // ...
    shared_memory_variable(type_for_debug, &debug_flag, DEBUG_FLAG_1);
```

Comment: Thank you. That was indeed the pointer (pardon the pun :) ) in the right direction I needed. Initially, the variable debug_flag was just a stacked variable (int debug_flag = 1) and was passed as &debug_flag but seeing that it didn't work, I changed it to a pointer based variable.

Answer (score 1):

You never set `debug_flag` to anything but `NULL`.

C is pass by value, so when you pass `debug_flag` to `shared_memory_variable` its value is copied to the parameter `variable`.  When you set the value of `variable` later on, this change is not propagated to `debug_flag`.  Inside the function, you are printing the value of `variable` rather than the value of `debug_flag`.